# Iterating through the firebase database

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to iterate over the firebase db variable in my App.js for my react app and am running into some issues. Here is the video I have been following along with - around 1 hour 9 minutes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7T48W0cwXM&t=44s

So basically they import and set up their firebase.js. Mine looks a little different because the syntax has changed since the video came out.
My firebase.js looks like:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from 

'firebase/auth'; 
     import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore" 
     const firebaseConfig = {   
     apiKey: "AIzaSyAomHkUyY4I8XD3rYq-LD2SbftJXj-L8Ug",   
     authDomain: "travelgram-39eba.firebaseapp.com",   
     projectId: "travelgram-39eba",   
     storageBucket: "travelgram-39eba.appspot.com",   
     messagingSenderId: "211989329504",   
     appId: "1:211989329504:web:b56e0357be92215bac7505",  
     measurementId: "G-Y90M6SQKYC" }; 

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
export const auth = getAuth(); 
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Now when I import {db} from "./firebase" - I want to iterate over it in the useEffect hook (just like in the video) but cant seem to figure out how to get the content from the firebase db.

Here is what I put from following the video:

```
  useEffect(() => {
       db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
         setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
  })
 }, [posts] )
```

But this shows an error:

App.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.db.collection is not a function

If I console.log(db) I get a long object that looks like:

```
FirebaseAppImpl {_isDeleted: false, _options: {…}, _config: {…}, _name: '[DEFAULT]', _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false, …}
_automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false
_config: {name: '[DEFAULT]', automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false}
_container: ComponentContainer {name: '[DEFAULT]', providers: Map(17)}
_isDeleted: false
_name: "[DEFAULT]"
_options: {apiKey: 'AIzaSyAomHkUyY4I8XD3rYq-LD2SbftJXj-L8Ug', authDomain: 'travelgram-39eba.firebaseapp.com', projectId: 'travelgram-39eba', storageBucket: 'travelgram-39eba.appspot.com', messagingSenderId: '211989329504', …}
automaticDataCollectionEnabled: (...)
config: (...)
container: (...)
isDeleted: (...)
name: (...)
options: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get the actual information from there. db.collections is undefined as well and I even tried using const db = getFirestore(app); instead of getDatabase and nothing has changed.

Any help is much appreciated!! can reach me by email as well jess_pesale@aol.com

Answer (score 0):

From your import statements, it seems like you're using the "Web Version 9" (modular) version, but the syntax you're using for your query is actually the "Version 8" (namespaced) syntax.

The syntax for the modular version looks like this:

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");
```

In your case, looks like you want realtime updates, so you need to do this:

```
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "cities", "SF"), (doc) => {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

See the documentation for [Setting Up Your Environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment), [Reading Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), and [Listening for Realtime Updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

**TLDR:** *Make sure your syntax for querying matches the syntax you used when you set up your project.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work: (for those wondering)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import './App.css';
import Post from './components/Post/Post';
import { db } from './firebase';
import {collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";


function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(collection(db, "posts"), (snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
       id: doc.id,
       post: doc.data()
      })))
    })
  }, [posts]);
```